# Polar Coordinates Differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, periodic-functions, stability-in-odes

[image: Q1]

$$x = r\cos(\theta);$$
$$y = r \sin(\theta);$$
$$r^2 = x^2 + y^2$$

We differentiate to get
$$2rr' = 2xx' + 2yy'$$ -> which simplifies to -> $$rr' = xx' +yy'$$

We plug in $r'$ which is given, then I have $r^2(|r-2|)(r-3) = r \cos(\theta)x' + r\sin(\theta)y'$

But I have not been given an equation with $x$ or $y$ so how can I solve this problem?

Thank You

Comment: I edited your post to get the $\LaTeX$ to work as well as I could in finite time.  Remember, it is generally better to put an *entire equation* between the "\$" signs than to break it down into pieces.  Cheers!

Comment: Also, are you sure you mean $r' = r \vert r - 2 \vert (r - 3)$ and not $r' = r (r - 2)(r - 3)$?

Comment: @RobertLewis yes. I am positive. Thank you for your help. I am just barely getting a hang of the syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response; yes $\LaTeX$ takes a while.  One thing you can do to learn stuff is to hit the "edit" button beneath questions and answers; you will then see the raw unrendered text and you can learn how people do things.  Cheers!

Comment: I didn't realize that the edit sign would show the unrendered text. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Glad to be of service!

Comment: Will r′=r(r−2)(r−3) change the solution? Or just the sign of the solution

Comment: The stability properties will be substantially different with $r' =  r (r - 2)(r - 3)$.  I'm trying to answer your question right now an I'll try and explain further there!

Comment: Thank you for your help Robert. You consistently post clear and easy to follow responses. I'm a fan of your work!

Comment: Hey, thanks!  We'd best knock off chatting here for a while lest we irritate the mods.  I'm working on an answer.  Will get back to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to convert to rectangular coordinates to solve your problem.

Note that you have three values for $r$ which make $r'=0$

These values are $r=0, r=2, r=3$

$r=0$ is the origin which is an equilibrium point. This equilibrium point is stable as you can figure it out by looking at $r'$ near $r=0$

$r=2$  is a limit cycle.  This limit cycle is unstable as you can check the sign of $r'$ for values of $r<2$ and close to $r=2$

$r=3$ is a limit cycle. This limit cycle is also unstable as you can check the values of $r'$ near $r=3$

Comment: Thank you for your response.

How can we make use of the information that (theta)' = -2? Is a periodic solution just the solutions that make the equation zero? 

Thank You

Comment: That simply says you have a uniform motion clockwise along the tragectories.

Comment: how would I go about drawing the phase portrait. Are there multiple rings?

Comment: You have two circles at $r=2$ and $r=3$ . Other trajectories are either spiraling  in or spiraling  out. Of course the center is fixed.